# (THREE.JS) calculate the custom UVs for custom Buffer Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, texture-mapping, indices

I am trying to create a curve wall using some vertices array in three JS.
What I will get in array is some base vertices in 2D which will be the bottom vertices of wall. These includes the center, lower and upper vertices which means it is two faced wall. based on these vertices, I added some wall height and convert that 2D to 3D.
Below is the code and working fiddle

```
/**
 * Created by Singh on 7/30/2018.
 */

var renderer, scene, camera;

init();
animate();


function init() {
    wallsGeometry = function(totalPoints){


    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({/*color: 0xff0000,*/ side: THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe : false});
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({/*color: 0x0044400, */side: THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe : true});

    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var geometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    var wallHeight = 200;


    var pointindices = [
        0,1,2,0,2,3,   //left

        5,4,7,5,7,6,   //right

        4,0,3,4,3,7,  //back

        1,5,6,1,6,2,    //front

        2,6,7,2,7,3,    //top

        5,1,0,5,0,4,  //bottom

    ];

    var pointindices2 = [
        1,0,2,1,3,2 , //left

        4,5,7,4,6,7,   //right

        0,4,3,0,7,3,  //back

        5,1,2,5,2,6,    //front

        6,2,7,6,3,7,    //top

        1,5,0,1,4,0,  //bottom

    ];

    var tempIndices = [];
    var tempIndices2 = [];


    for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < pointindices.length; j++) {
            tempIndices[pointindices.length * i + j] = 4 * i + pointindices[j];
        }
    }
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < pointindices2.length; j++) {
            tempIndices2[pointindices2.length * i + j] = 4 * i + pointindices2[j];
        }
    }


    var tempVerMesh = [];
    var tempVerMesh2 = [];

    var indices = new Uint32Array( tempIndices       );
    var pointsArray = { // for testing
        pointUpper1: new THREE.Vector3(),
        pointUpper2: new THREE.Vector3(),
        pointCenter1: new THREE.Vector3(),
        pointCenter2: new THREE.Vector3(),
        pointLower1: new THREE.Vector3(),
        pointLower2: new THREE.Vector3()
    };

console.log(totalPoints);
    /*function generateUVs(geometry) {
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();

        var max = geometry.boundingBox.max, min = geometry.boundingBox.min;

        var offset = new THREE.Vector3(0 - min.x, 0 - min.y);
        var range = new THREE.Vector3(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);
        var faces = geometry.faces;

        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < faces.length ; i++) {

            var v1 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].a],
                v2 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].b],
                v3 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].c];

            geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
                new THREE.Vector3((v1.x + offset.x)/range.x ,(v1.y + offset.y)/range.y),
                new THREE.Vector3((v2.x + offset.x)/range.x ,(v2.y + offset.y)/range.y),
                new THREE.Vector3((v3.x + offset.x)/range.x ,(v3.y + offset.y)/range.y),
            ]);
        }
        geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
        return geometry;
    }*/
        for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints.lower.length    ; i++) {
            pointsArray.pointCenter1 = totalPoints.center[i];
            //pointsArray.pointCenter2 = totalPoints.center[i + 1];
            pointsArray.pointLower1 = totalPoints.lower[i];
            //pointsArray.pointLower2 = totalPoints.lower[i + 1];
            pointsArray.pointUpper1 = totalPoints.upper[i];
            //pointsArray.pointUpper2 = totalPoints.upper[i + 1];
            tempVerMesh.push(pointsArray.pointCenter1.x, pointsArray.pointCenter1.y, pointsArray.pointCenter1.z);
            tempVerMesh.push(pointsArray.pointLower1.x, pointsArray.pointLower1.y, pointsArray.pointLower1.z);
            tempVerMesh.push(pointsArray.pointLower1.x, pointsArray.pointLower1.y + wallHeight, pointsArray.pointLower1.z);
            tempVerMesh.push(pointsArray.pointCenter1.x, pointsArray.pointCenter1.y + wallHeight, pointsArray.pointCenter1.z);



            tempVerMesh2.push(pointsArray.pointCenter1.x, pointsArray.pointCenter1.y, pointsArray.pointCenter1.z);
            tempVerMesh2.push(pointsArray.pointUpper1.x, pointsArray.pointUpper1.y, pointsArray.pointUpper1.z);

            tempVerMesh2.push(pointsArray.pointUpper1.x, pointsArray.pointUpper1.y + wallHeight, pointsArray.pointUpper1.z );
            tempVerMesh2.push(pointsArray.pointCenter1.x, pointsArray.pointCenter1.y + wallHeight, pointsArray.pointCenter1.z);

        }


    var vertices = new Float32Array(tempVerMesh);
    var vertices2 = new Float32Array(tempVerMesh2);

    //var uvs = new Float32Array(pointUVs);

            geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
            geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));
            //geometry.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));

            geometry.computeFaceNormals();
            geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    console.log(geometry);

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);



    var indices2 = new Uint32Array(tempIndices2);
    geometry2.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices2, 3));
    geometry2.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices2, 1));



    geometry2.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry2.computeVertexNormals();

   /*var geom = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(geometry2);
    var temp = generateUVs(geom);
    geometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(temp);*/
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);


    //geometry2.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs2, 2));


    return [mesh,mesh2];

};

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 400;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

var arrow;
var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

var points = {
    pointUpper1: new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, -20),
    pointUpper2: new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, -20),
    pointCenter1: new THREE.Vector3(-100, 0, 0),
    pointCenter2: new THREE.Vector3(150, 0, 0),
    pointLower1: new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, 20),
    pointLower2: new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, 20)
};

var totalPoints = {
    center : [new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, 0),new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),new THREE.Vector3(50, 0, 0),new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 0),new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, 0)],
    lower : [new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, 20),new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 20),new THREE.Vector3(50, 0, 20),new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 20),new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, 20)],
    upper : [new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, -20),new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -20),new THREE.Vector3(50, 0, -20),new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, -20),new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, -20)]
};

var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 10, 10);

function initPoints(){
    var point1mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff00}));
    point1mesh.position.copy(points.pointUpper1);
    scene.add(point1mesh);

    var point2mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff}));
    point2mesh.position.copy(points.pointUpper2);
    scene.add(point2mesh);

    var point3mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff00}));
    point3mesh.position.copy(points.pointCenter1);
    scene.add(point3mesh);

    var point4mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff}));
    point4mesh.position.copy(points.pointCenter2);
    scene.add(point4mesh);

    var point5mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff00}));
    point5mesh.position.copy(points.pointLower1);
    scene.add(point5mesh);

    var point6mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff}));
    point6mesh.position.copy(points.pointLower2);
    scene.add(point6mesh);
}
 initPoints();

    var mesh = new wallsGeometry(totalPoints);



function createArrow() {
    var length = 30;
    arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
        THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp,
        new THREE.Vector3(),
        length,
        0xffff00,
        1.5 * length,
        1.25 * length
    );
    arrow.position.z = 10;
    scene.add(arrow);
}
// arrow
createArrow();

function updateArrow(object, point, face) {
    arrow.position.copy(point);
    var normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3().getNormalMatrix( object.matrixWorld );
    var normal = face.normal.clone().applyMatrix3( normalMatrix ).normalize();
    arrow.setDirection(normal);
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    rayCaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObject(mesh[0], true);
    var i, il, intersect;
    if (intersects[0]) {
        var face = intersects[0].face;
        var point = intersects[0].point;
        var object = intersects[0].object;
        updateArrow(object, point, face);
    }
}
/*         var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    textureLoader.load('./textures/Capture.PNG', function (texture) {
        console.log('texture loaded');
        texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

        //mesh[0].material.map = texture;
        var vertexNormalsHelper = new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( mesh[0], 10 );
        mesh[0].add( vertexNormalsHelper );
    }); */
        scene.add(mesh[0]);

 /*     textureLoader.load('./textures/abc.jpg', function (texture) {
    console.log('texture loaded');
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    //mesh[1].material.map = texture;
    var vertexNormalsHelper = new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( mesh[1], 10 );
    mesh[1].add( vertexNormalsHelper );
}); */
        scene.add(mesh[1]);

//
var Orbitcontrols = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
Orbitcontrols.update();

}

// render
function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// animate
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/simar_aneja/fsmw8znq/6/

In the fiddle you can see that wall is building properly and you can increase the vertices and loop of creating those indices, in the start. Now I want to add UVs to this bufferGeometry, I tried converting to geometry and then calculated faceVertexUVs, but this is not the right way. Can anyone suggest me the further path where I can attach different textures only at the front side, different on top side. And it should be in such a way that no matter how many vertices comes, Uvs should get calculated based on length of vertices. I have some Idea but not getting how to make it different for diff sides of wall.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to create the geometry this way? It may be easier to create a PlaneBufferGeometry (with automatic UVs) and deform it, or create the model in Blender, UV map it, and export.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy : No it has to be this way only. specification is that end user has a control in 2D and can create any type/length of wall and then I need to take those x,z coordinates and convert it into 3D... just check 
[link](https://floorplanner.com/demo)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a UV box-unwrapping I fixed up for ya. Maybe you'll find it helpful...

I also put your fiddle into a snippet you can run below...

```
function boxUnwrapUVs(geometry) {
  if (!geometry.boundingBox) geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  var sz = geometry.boundingBox.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
  var center = geometry.boundingBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3())
  var min = geometry.boundingBox.min;
  if (geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].length == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
      geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2()]);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
    var face = geometry.faces[i];
    var faceUVs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i]
    var va = geometry.vertices[geometry.faces[i].a]
    var vb = geometry.vertices[geometry.faces[i].b]
    var vc = geometry.vertices[geometry.faces[i].c]
    var vab = new THREE.Vector3().copy(vb).sub(va)
    var vac = new THREE.Vector3().copy(vc).sub(va)
    //now we have 2 vectors to get the cross product of...
    var vcross = new THREE.Vector3().copy(vab).cross(vac);
    //Find the largest axis of the plane normal...
    vcross.set(Math.abs(vcross.x), Math.abs(vcross.y), Math.abs(vcross.z))
    var majorAxis = vcross.x > vcross.y ? (vcross.x > vcross.z ? 'x' : vcross.y > vcross.z ? 'y' : vcross.y > vcross.z) : vcross.y > vcross.z ? 'y' : 'z'
    //Take the other two axis from the largest axis
    var uAxis = majorAxis == 'x' ? 'y' : majorAxis == 'y' ? 'x' : 'x';
    var vAxis = majorAxis == 'x' ? 'z' : majorAxis == 'y' ? 'z' : 'y';
    faceUVs[0].set((va[uAxis] - min[uAxis]) / sz[uAxis], (va[vAxis] - min[vAxis]) / sz[vAxis])
    faceUVs[1].set((vb[uAxis] - min[uAxis]) / sz[uAxis], (vb[vAxis] - min[vAxis]) / sz[vAxis])
    faceUVs[2].set((vc[uAxis] - min[uAxis]) / sz[uAxis], (vc[vAxis] - min[vAxis]) / sz[vAxis])
  }
  geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}
geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(geometry)
boxUnwrapUVs(geometry)
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

```js
/**
 * Created by Singh on 7/30/2018.
 */

var renderer, scene, camera;

init();
animate();


function init() {
  wallsGeometry = function(totalPoints) {

    var rrnd = (min, max) => (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
    var irnd = (rng) => (Math.random() * rng) | 0

    function makeRndCanvas() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = canvas.height = 128;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var srnd = (rng) => (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2 * rng
      var irnd = (rng) => ((Math.random() * rng) | 0)
      for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < canvas.width; y++) {
          ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${irnd(256)},${irnd(256)},${irnd(256)},1.0)`
          ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
      }
      ctx.fillStyle = '#ffff00'
      ctx.fillText("WAHOO", 3, 64)
      return canvas;
    }


    function makeRndTexture() {
      var tex = new THREE.Texture(makeRndCanvas())
      tex.minFilter = // THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
        tex.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter; //THREE.LinearFilter;

      tex.wrapS = tex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      //tex.repeat.set(0.01, 0.01);
      tex.needsUpdate = true;
      return tex;
    }

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ /*color: 0xff0000,*/
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      wireframe: false,
      map: makeRndTexture()
    });
    var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ /*color: 0x0044400, */
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      wireframe: true
    });

    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var geometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    var wallHeight = 200;


    var pointindices = [
      0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, //left

      5, 4, 7, 5, 7, 6, //right

      4, 0, 3, 4, 3, 7, //back

      1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, //front

      2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 3, //top

      5, 1, 0, 5, 0, 4, //bottom

    ];

    var pointindices2 = [
      1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, //left

      4, 5, 7, 4, 6, 7, //right

      0, 4, 3, 0, 7, 3, //back

      5, 1, 2, 5, 2, 6, //front

      6, 2, 7, 6, 3, 7, //top

      1, 5, 0, 1, 4, 0, //bottom

    ];

    var tempIndices = [];
    var tempIndices2 = [];


    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < pointindices.length; j++) {
        tempIndices[pointindices.length * i + j] = 4 * i + pointindices[j];
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < pointindices2.length; j++) {
        tempIndices2[pointindices2.length * i + j] = 4 * i + pointindices2[j];
      }
    }


    var tempVerMesh = [];
    var tempVerMesh2 = [];

    var indices = new Uint32Array(tempIndices);
    var pointsArray = { // for testing
      pointUpper1: new THREE.Vector3(),
      pointUpper2: new THREE.Vector3(),
      pointCenter1: new THREE.Vector3(),
      pointCenter2: new THREE.Vector3(),
      pointLower1: new THREE.Vector3(),
      pointLower2: new THREE.Vector3()
    };

    console.log(totalPoints);
    /*function generateUVs(geometry) {
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();

        var max = geometry.boundingBox.max, min = geometry.boundingBox.min;

        var offset = new THREE.Vector3(0 - min.x, 0 - min.y);
        var range = new THREE.Vector3(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);
        var faces = geometry.faces;

        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < faces.length ; i++) {

            var v1 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].a],
                v2 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].b],
                v3 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].c];

            geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
                new THREE.Vector3((v1.x + offset.x)/range.x ,(v1.y + offset.y)/range.y),
                new THREE.Vector3((v2.x + offset.x)/range.x ,(v2.y + offset.y)/range.y),
                new THREE.Vector3((v3.x + offset.x)/range.x ,(v3.y + offset.y)/range.y),
            ]);
        }
        geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
        return geometry;
    }*/
    for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints.lower.length; i++) {
      pointsArray.pointCenter1 = totalPoints.center[i];
      //pointsArray.pointCenter2 = totalPoints.center[i + 1];
      pointsArray.pointLower1 = totalPoints.lower[i];
      //pointsArray.pointLower2 = totalPoints.lower[i + 1];
      pointsArray.pointUpper1 = totalPoints.upper[i];
      //pointsArray.pointUpper2 = totalPoints.upper[i + 1];
      tempVerMesh.push(pointsArray.pointCenter1.x, pointsArray.pointCenter1.y, pointsArray.pointCenter1.z);
      tempVerMesh.push(pointsArray.pointLower1.x, pointsArray.pointLower1.y, pointsArray.pointLower1.z);
      tempVerMesh.push(pointsArray.pointLower1.x, pointsArray.pointLower1.y + wallHeight, pointsArray.pointLower1.z);
      tempVerMesh.push(pointsArray.pointCenter1.x, pointsArray.pointCenter1.y + wallHeight, pointsArray.pointCenter1.z);



      tempVerMesh2.push(pointsArray.pointCenter1.x, pointsArray.pointCenter1.y, pointsArray.pointCenter1.z);
      tempVerMesh2.push(pointsArray.pointUpper1.x, pointsArray.pointUpper1.y, pointsArray.pointUpper1.z);

      tempVerMesh2.push(pointsArray.pointUpper1.x, pointsArray.pointUpper1.y + wallHeight, pointsArray.pointUpper1.z);
      tempVerMesh2.push(pointsArray.pointCenter1.x, pointsArray.pointCenter1.y + wallHeight, pointsArray.pointCenter1.z);

    }


    var vertices = new Float32Array(tempVerMesh);
    var vertices2 = new Float32Array(tempVerMesh2);

    //var uvs = new Float32Array(pointUVs);

    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
    geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));
    //geometry.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));

    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    console.log(geometry);

    function boxUnwrapUVs(geometry) {
      if (!geometry.boundingBox) geometry.computeBoundingBox();
      var sz = geometry.boundingBox.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
      var center = geometry.boundingBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3())
      var min = geometry.boundingBox.min;
      if (geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].length == 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
          geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2()]);
        }
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
        var face = geometry.faces[i];
        var faceUVs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i]
        var va = geometry.vertices[geometry.faces[i].a]
        var vb = geometry.vertices[geometry.faces[i].b]
        var vc = geometry.vertices[geometry.faces[i].c]
        var vab = new THREE.Vector3().copy(vb).sub(va)
        var vac = new THREE.Vector3().copy(vc).sub(va)
        //now we have 2 vectors to get the cross product of...
        var vcross = new THREE.Vector3().copy(vab).cross(vac);
        //Find the largest axis of the plane normal...
        vcross.set(Math.abs(vcross.x), Math.abs(vcross.y), Math.abs(vcross.z))
        var majorAxis = vcross.x > vcross.y ? (vcross.x > vcross.z ? 'x' : vcross.y > vcross.z ? 'y' : vcross.y > vcross.z) : vcross.y > vcross.z ? 'y' : 'z'
        //Take the other two axis from the largest axis
        var uAxis = majorAxis == 'x' ? 'y' : majorAxis == 'y' ? 'x' : 'x';
        var vAxis = majorAxis == 'x' ? 'z' : majorAxis == 'y' ? 'z' : 'y';
        faceUVs[0].set((va[uAxis] - min[uAxis]) / sz[uAxis], (va[vAxis] - min[vAxis]) / sz[vAxis])
        faceUVs[1].set((vb[uAxis] - min[uAxis]) / sz[uAxis], (vb[vAxis] - min[vAxis]) / sz[vAxis])
        faceUVs[2].set((vc[uAxis] - min[uAxis]) / sz[uAxis], (vc[vAxis] - min[vAxis]) / sz[vAxis])
      }
      geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    }
    geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(geometry)
    boxUnwrapUVs(geometry)
    geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry)
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);






    var indices2 = new Uint32Array(tempIndices2);
    geometry2.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices2, 3));
    geometry2.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices2, 1));



    geometry2.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry2.computeVertexNormals();

    /*      var geom = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(geometry2);
            var temp = generateUVs(geom);
            geometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(temp);*/
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2);


    //geometry2.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs2, 2));


    return [mesh, mesh2];

  };

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 400;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var arrow;
  var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
  light.position.set(200, 200, 200)
  scene.add(light)
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);

  var points = {
    pointUpper1: new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, -20),
    pointUpper2: new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, -20),
    pointCenter1: new THREE.Vector3(-100, 0, 0),
    pointCenter2: new THREE.Vector3(150, 0, 0),
    pointLower1: new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, 20),
    pointLower2: new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, 20)
  };

  var totalPoints = {
    center: [new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(50, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, 0)],
    lower: [new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, 20), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 20), new THREE.Vector3(50, 0, 20), new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 20), new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, 20)],
    upper: [new THREE.Vector3(-70, 0, -20), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -20), new THREE.Vector3(50, 0, -20), new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, -20), new THREE.Vector3(130, 0, -20)]
  };

  var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 10, 10);

  function initPoints() {
    var point1mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff00
    }));
    point1mesh.position.copy(points.pointUpper1);
    scene.add(point1mesh);

    var point2mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x0000ff
    }));
    point2mesh.position.copy(points.pointUpper2);
    scene.add(point2mesh);

    var point3mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff00
    }));
    point3mesh.position.copy(points.pointCenter1);
    scene.add(point3mesh);

    var point4mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x0000ff
    }));
    point4mesh.position.copy(points.pointCenter2);
    scene.add(point4mesh);

    var point5mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff00
    }));
    point5mesh.position.copy(points.pointLower1);
    scene.add(point5mesh);

    var point6mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x0000ff
    }));
    point6mesh.position.copy(points.pointLower2);
    scene.add(point6mesh);
  }
  initPoints();

  var mesh = new wallsGeometry(totalPoints);


  function createArrow() {
    var length = 30;
    arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(
      THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp,
      new THREE.Vector3(),
      length,
      0xffff00,
      1.5 * length,
      1.25 * length
    );
    arrow.position.z = 10;
    scene.add(arrow);
  }
  // arrow
  createArrow();

  function updateArrow(object, point, face) {
    arrow.position.copy(point);
    var normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3().getNormalMatrix(object.matrixWorld);
    var normal = face.normal.clone().applyMatrix3(normalMatrix).normalize();
    arrow.setDirection(normal);
  }

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    rayCaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObject(mesh[0], true);
    var i, il, intersect;
    if (intersects[0]) {
      var face = intersects[0].face;
      var point = intersects[0].point;
      var object = intersects[0].object;
      updateArrow(object, point, face);
    }
  }
  /*         var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      textureLoader.load('./textures/Capture.PNG', function (texture) {
          console.log('texture loaded');
          texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
      
          //mesh[0].material.map = texture;
          var vertexNormalsHelper = new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( mesh[0], 10 );
          mesh[0].add( vertexNormalsHelper );
      }); */
  scene.add(mesh[0]);

  /*     textureLoader.load('./textures/abc.jpg', function (texture) {
      console.log('texture loaded');
      texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
      //mesh[1].material.map = texture;
      var vertexNormalsHelper = new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( mesh[1], 10 );
      mesh[1].add( vertexNormalsHelper );
  }); */
  scene.add(mesh[1]);

  //
  var Orbitcontrols = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  Orbitcontrols.update();

}

// render
function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// animate
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, I understand it but I mentioned that I don't want to convert it back into geometry. It has to be managed in buffer Geometry along with UV and indices only. Thats why I also disabled my function, also bounding box will make issues if wall is tilted/rotated. box size wil come as square and if we make this as curve, all the intermediate vertices may not be at the equal distances. for now, I have calculate distances. But in this, we can take wall segments as 5 and then try to map UV. I also tried but pushing one UV along with one vertex, but stuck on the top side of the wall .

Comment: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simar_aneja/kzbmwL57/2/)

this is the  updated code you can check for reference, what I am trying to do.

there is another way also I am trying by sending vertices repeatedly, but there I am stuck with automatic indices calculation.

[another method](https://jsfiddle.net/simar_aneja/y3u7kswo/) .. this one I stuck at indices ..

both fiddles will not work, you need to copy the code and run

Comment: geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry)

Comment: UV unwrapping of complex objects is an entire active field of research, and people make products that sell for 100s of dollars, to perform unwrapping. At some point you're going to have to find a compromise, or start doing some serious research.

Comment: Maybe start with identifying exactly how you want the unwrapping to be.. like.. make a screenshot in blender or something, and use some actual textures that will be representative of what you are going to be using.

Comment: Your vertex indices for the wireframe object are wrong.. also, don't stress too much about geometry vs buffergeometry. just use the one that is most convenient and convert between them if you need to.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help, just the last bit of doubt I will ask. I will try to start with geometry only and not use buffer geometry, for that I need to create faces dynamically. Do you have any logic around that,how to create faces dynamically based on vertices passed and push them..or the way I am doing indices, I should do for faces too ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177360/discussion-between-manthrax-and-sim).